# Outlook showing URL to old exchange server for Webmail

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

I have successfully decommissioned an Exchange 2013 server and now running on a single Exchange 2013 server (looking to add additional soon).

However in Outlook on my clients under the File tab, next to the Account settings it shows the URL to my old exchange server for Web mail.

[image]

Is there a way to change this?

On my exchange server this command:

```
Get-OutlookAnywhere | fl
```

Is showing that my `Internal Hostname` is the correct Exchange server.  As well as these commands also show the correct exchange server:

```
Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory
Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory
Get-OABVirtualDirectory
Get-ClientAccessServer
```

Here is the [article I was looking at for reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529912(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so maybe I was a bit hasty.  After a while the new Exchange URL came through.